# разница между module.require() и require() node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, модули

Извиняюсь за свой английский, но в [документации по модулям node.js](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) всё написано так, что меня с переводчиком не хватило:

> The module.require method provides a way to load a module as if
>   require() was called from the original module.
>
> Note that in order to do this, you must get a reference to the module
>   object. Since require() returns the module.exports, and the module is
>   typically only available within a specific module's code, it must be
>   explicitly exported in order to be used.

Answer (score 4):

`module.require` и `require` - это одно и то же. Разница лишь в том, что `module.require` - это метод, а `require` - это параметр :)

---

Практически же, наличие метода `module.require` означает, что если у вас есть ссылка на некоторый модуль (что само по себе не просто, ведь `module` - это тоже локальный параметр) - то можно вызвать require так, как будто она выполняется из этого самого другого модуля.

Единственный модуль, который доступен "из коробки" - это `require.main`, главный модуль (т.е. тот модуль, который и был запущен). Это позволяет делать трюки наподобие `require.main.require('./config')`, загружая конфиг не относительно текущего модуля - а относительно главного. Другие модули, кроме конфига, так лучше не грузить, потому что каждый модуль должен работать независимо от того как и откуда он был запущен.

---

PS функцию, параметрами которой являются `module` и `require`, можно найти в документации. Это [функция-обертка над модулями](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper), внутрь которой неявно помещается каждый модуль перед тем как начать исполняться.

Answer (score 1):

Тут написано что метод module.require предоставляет возможность загрузки модуля, если метод будет вызван из основного модуля. при этом метод вернет то, что присвоено переменной module.exports внутри модуля.

Допустим у вас есть модуль: `myModule.js`

```
module.exports = {
    moduleFunction: function(arg) {
        console.log(arg);
    }
}
```

и основной скрипт `index.js`

```
var myModule = require('./myModule');
myModule.moduleFunction('hello');
```

вот так вы загружаете ваш модуль и вызываете метод `moduleFunction`

Хочу заметить это актуально не только для node.js но и для обычного web, например с [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Там написано, что module.require позволяет загрузить модуль *как если бы* он загружался из родительского модуля